# Multivalue iteration in Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, iterator

I'm currently building a model that would simulate three different set of orders (shapefile format) by using the **[Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000004v000000)** tool of network analyst. The model I built runs correctly but shows me only the first delivery solution in the excel file. My aim is to have all the different route results into an Excel file (or even multiple). Does anybody know how to do that or fix the model? I also add that one issue is related to the fact that I cannot specify the input data in the delivery "Add location" during different iterations (only the first one is considered).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Iterate Multivalue takes as input a *single* input parameter which has multiple values. You've connected 3 inputs to your iterator. I assume the model is reading only the first one and ignoring the others. So have a look at the help file it tells you to create a variable then set that to Multi-value and then you connect that to the iterator. This make resolve your other issue?